# Access a Multidimensional Array Value in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am working with Laravel 8.0 with the Quickbooks API,
When I run a quickbooks query to get all the customers, I get back a response that looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPCustomer Object
        (
            [Taxable] => true
            [BillAddr] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPPhysicalAddress Object
                (
                    [Id] => 2
                    [Line1] => 4581 Finch St.
                    [Line2] => 
                    [Line3] => 
                    [Line4] => 
                    [Line5] => 
                    [City] => Bayshore
                    [Country] => 
                    [CountryCode] => 
                    [County] => 
                    [CountrySubDivisionCode] => CA
                    [PostalCode] => 94326
                    [PostalCodeSuffix] => 
                    [Lat] => INVALID
                    [Long] => INVALID
                    [Tag] => 
                    [Note] => 
                )

            [ShipAddr] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPPhysicalAddress Object
                (
                    [Id] => 2
                    [Line1] => 4581 Finch St.
                    [Line2] => 
                    [Line3] => 
                    [Line4] => 
                    [Line5] => 
                    [City] => Bayshore
                    [Country] => 
                    [CountryCode] => 
                    [County] => 
                    [CountrySubDivisionCode] => CA
                    [PostalCode] => 94326
                    [PostalCodeSuffix] => 
                    [Lat] => INVALID
                    [Long] => INVALID
                    [Tag] => 
                    [Note] => 
                )

            [OtherAddr] => 
            [ContactName] => 
            [AltContactName] => 
            [Notes] => 
            [Job] => false
            [BillWithParent] => false
            [RootCustomerRef] => 
            [ParentRef] => 
            [Level] => 
            [CustomerTypeRef] => 
            [SalesTermRef] => 
            [SalesRepRef] => 
            [TaxGroupCodeRef] => 
            [TaxRateRef] => 
            [PaymentMethodRef] => 
            [CCDetail] => 
            [PriceLevelRef] => 
            [Balance] => 239.00
            [OpenBalanceDate] => 
            [BalanceWithJobs] => 239.00
            [CreditLimit] => 
            [AcctNum] => 
            [CurrencyRef] => USD
            [OverDueBalance] => 
            [TotalRevenue] => 
            [TotalExpense] => 
            [PreferredDeliveryMethod] => Print
            [ResaleNum] => 
            [JobInfo] => 
            [TDSEnabled] => 
            [CustomerEx] => 
            [SecondaryTaxIdentifier] => 
            [ARAccountRef] => 
            [PrimaryTaxIdentifier] => 
            [TaxExemptionReasonId] => 
            [IsProject] => false
            [BusinessNumber] => 
            [GSTIN] => 
            [GSTRegistrationType] => 
            [IsCISContractor] => 
            [ClientCompanyId] => 
            [ClientEntityId] => 0
            [IntuitId] => 
            [Organization] => 
            [Title] => 
            [GivenName] => Amy
            [MiddleName] => 
            [FamilyName] => Lauterbach
            [Suffix] => 
            [FullyQualifiedName] => Amy's Bird Sanctuary
            [CompanyName] => Amy's Bird Sanctuary
            [DisplayName] => Amy's Bird Sanctuary
            [PrintOnCheckName] => Amy's Bird Sanctuary
            [UserId] => 
            [Active] => true
            [V4IDPseudonym] => 002098e9355296552b4ab8a26366974b39e91e
            [PrimaryPhone] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPTelephoneNumber Object
                (
                    [Id] => 
                    [DeviceType] => 
                    [CountryCode] => 
                    [AreaCode] => 
                    [ExchangeCode] => 
                    [Extension] => 
                    [FreeFormNumber] => (650) 555-3311
                    [Default] => 
                    [Tag] => 
                )

            [AlternatePhone] => 
            [Mobile] => 
            [Fax] => 
            [PrimaryEmailAddr] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPEmailAddress Object
                (
                    [Id] => 
                    [Address] => Birds@Intuit.com
                    [Default] => 
                    [Tag] => 
                )

            [WebAddr] => 
            [OtherContactInfo] => 
            [DefaultTaxCodeRef] => 
            [Id] => 1
            [SyncToken] => 0
            [MetaData] => QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPModificationMetaData Object
                (
                    [CreatedByRef] => 
                    [CreateTime] => 2020-12-31T16:48:43-08:00
                    [LastModifiedByRef] => 
                    [LastUpdatedTime] => 2021-01-07T13:39:32-08:00
                    [LastChangedInQB] => 
                    [Synchronized] => 
                )

            [CustomField] => 
            [AttachableRef] => 
            [domain] => 
            [status] => 
            [sparse] => 
        )
```

I pass off that data to the view, and then inside my blade template I foreach the customers like so.

```
        @foreach($customers as $customer)  

        <h1>{{ $customer->GivenName.' '.$customer->FamilyName }}</h1>  
                
        @endforeach
```

My issue is when I to access the BillAddr inside of my foreach.
**{{$customer->BillAddr->Line1 }}**

```
        @foreach($customers as $customer)  

        <h1>{{ $customer->GivenName.' '.$customer->FamilyName }}</h1>  
        <h2>address: {{$customer->BillAddr->Line1 }}<h2>
                 
        @endforeach
```

no matter what I can't seem to access the data, I've tried to access it using different ways, such as.

- {{$customer->BillAddr->Line1 }}
- {{$customer->['BillAddr']['Line1'] }}
- {{$customer['BillAddr']['Line1'] }}

etc..

I'm getting the error

> errorException
> Trying to get property 'Line1' of non-object

If I try to access the property like this

```
$customer->BillAddr['Line1']
```

Then I also get an error, but its a different error.

> Cannot use object of type QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPPhysicalAddress as array

Comment: Hi Brandon, Is the [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) usage necessary for your particular project?

Comment: It is only necessary to display rows with 4 columns in bootstrap.
Do you think that is why this is happeneing? let me try it without it.

-- Update: It's still complaining.

Comment: Hi Brandon, I'm not sure if that is the issue, but I was curious because it seems to add a little complexity to the task at hand from my at-a-glance check of that part.

Comment: I tried it without the array_chunk() and i still get the same error.

Comment: Thanks for trying that. It seems to me that your `$customer` variable might not be getting set with a customer object. The `non-object` part of your error message might help support that thought. Would it be possible to show part of your related controller code that relates to this view? In cases like this, it might be helpful to temporarily add a `print_r($customers);` type of line in your code to check and see if that variable has any data or if it is empty.

Comment: I used {{ print_r($customers) }} inside of my blade template and I get back all the data....

Comment: I ran a quick test to make sure, using test classes called `A` and `B` with an inner `$c` variable and the `$object->object->var` pattern should normally work as you are expecting in PHP 7.3 (as long as I'm understanding correctly). Do you have a link for the QuickBooksOnline API you are using? I tried looking for it earlier, but I couldn't find the exact class files for the objects you are using here. Do you think it's possible that there is a special "get" type of method required to retrieve the inner `Line1` type of variables from the `IPPPhysicalAddress` class from your array data example?

Comment: Obviously `$customer->BillAddr` is an object of type `QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPPhysicalAddress`. Surely you must have some API documentation telling you what methods or properties are available to you from this object?

Comment: I am using this package as a wrapper for the QuickBooks API inside Laravel
https://github.com/spinen/laravel-quickbooks-client

Yes I was actually thinking the same thing, because when I tried to access it like this,
$customer->BillAddr['Line1']

I got this error back.
Cannot use object of type QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPPhysicalAddress as array

But I wouldn't have a clue how to go about this special get method.
Would I have to pass this object to my view?

Comment: Thank You guys for your answers, I found the issue and pasted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was because some of the data was missing, and Laravel complains about this...

So this is the answer to solve the problem, using the optional() helper method.

```
{{ optional($customer->BillAddr)->Line1 }}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you found the issue! :)

Comment: Thx! I appreciate your help as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$customer->BillAddr[0]['Line1'];
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Getting Back

Error
Cannot use object of type QuickBooksOnline\API\Data\IPPPhysicalAddress as array

Comment: plz show me the result of dd($customer->BillAddr);

Comment: I found the issue and pasted the answer, thank you for your answers.